# HTML collapse table row with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to collapse row after click on button "collapse".
But nothing happens.

What I am doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr#test').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GridGlyphs';
  src: url('../MvcGrid/Fonts/GridGlyphs.woff') format('woff');
}

.mvc-grid {
  line-height: 1.25em;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.mvc-grid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mvc-grid th {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  position: relative;
}

.mvc-grid th,
.mvc-grid td {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  padding: 0.75em;
}

.mvc-grid .filterable {
  padding-right: 3.5em;
}

.mvc-grid .sortable,
.mvc-grid .mvc-grid-filter {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mvc-grid .asc::after {
  padding-left: 3px;
  content: '\2193';
}

.mvc-grid .desc::after {
  padding-left: 3px;
  content: '\2191';
}

.mvc-grid-hidden,
.mvc-grid-options {
  display: none;
}

.mvc-grid-filter {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  font-family: 'GridGlyphs';
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 2.75em;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-filter:focus,
.mvc-grid-filter:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  color: inherit;
}

.mvc-grid-filter::before {
  content: '\0041';
}

.mvc-grid-filter.applied::before {
  content: '\0042';
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .filterable {
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters th div {
  display: flex;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value {
  border: 0.5px solid #aaaaaa;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 0.2em;
  flex: 1;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters input.mvc-grid-value {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value.invalid {
  outline-color: #dc3545;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value::placeholder {
  color: #bbbbbb;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #bbbbbb;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-filter {
  border: 0.5px solid #aaaaaa;
  flex: 0 0 2.125em;
  position: static;
  height: 2.125em;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters [readonly] {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters.mvc-grid-headers .filterable {
  padding: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters.mvc-grid-headers .mvc-grid-value {
  padding: 0.625em 3.5em 0.625em 0.75em;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters.mvc-grid-headers .mvc-grid-filter {
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
}

.mvc-grid-popup {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 12em;
  font-size: 1rem;
  z-index: 1100;
}

.mvc-grid-popup.mvc-grid-guid-filter {
  min-width: 20em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-arrow {
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  top: -8px;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-arrow::after {
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 9px solid #cccccc;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  z-index: -1;
  left: -8px;
  top: -1px;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-content {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-group {
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-operator {
  text-align: center;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-actions {
  padding: 0.4em 0 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-value,
.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-method,
.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-operator {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0 0.2em;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 100%;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-operator {
  width: auto;
}

.mvc-grid-popup input.mvc-grid-value {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-value.invalid {
  outline-color: #dc3545;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-apply,
.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-cancel {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 4em;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-apply {
  background-color: #28a745;
  border-color: #28a745;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-apply:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2em rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.5);
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-cancel {
  background-color: #dc3545;
  border-color: #dc3545;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-cancel:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2em rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.5);
}

.mvc-grid-pager,
.mvc-grid-empty-row {
  text-align: center;
}

.mvc-grid-pager button {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  min-width: 2em;
  color: #337ab7;
}

.mvc-grid-pager button:focus,
.mvc-grid-pager button:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: #014c8c;
}

.mvc-grid-pager .active,
.mvc-grid-pager .active:focus,
.mvc-grid-pager .active:hover {
  background-color: #0275d8;
  border-color: #0275d8;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.mvc-grid-pager .disabled,
.mvc-grid-pager .disabled:focus,
.mvc-grid-pager .disabled:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: #777777;
  outline: none;
}

.mvc-grid-page-sizes {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-page-sizes select {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  font: inherit;
}

.mvc-grid-page-sizes input {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 2.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-loader {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  justify-content: center;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: wait;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-loading {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mvc-grid-loading>div>div {
  animation: loader-points 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 0.75em;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-loading>div>div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.mvc-grid-loading>div>div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

@keyframes loader-points {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="test">
      <td><button class="clickme">collapse</button></td>
      <td>name1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8" class="parent">
        <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="" data-filter-mode="ExcelRow" data-source-url="">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr class="mvc-grid-headers ">
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="test">
      <td><button class="clickme">collapse</button></td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8" class="parent">

        <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="" data-filter-mode="ExcelRow" data-source-url="">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr class="mvc-grid-headers ">
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr clss="test">
      <td><button class="clickme">collapse</button></td>
      <td>name3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8" class="parent">

        <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="" data-filter-mode="ExcelRow" data-source-url="">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr class="mvc-grid-headers ">
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) all following siblings of the element until ( not including ) the specified element.

The button and the `tr#test` are not siblings. BUtton doesn't have any siblings so there is nothing to show.

So you need to first select the button's parent (tr) and use nextAll on that tr which is siblings with the `tr#test`. Also as it has been pointed out in the other answer, do not use duplicate id's but use classes instead `class='test'`

I guess in the 'real' app you will have more siblings between the button's parent `tr` and the `tr` you want to hide.

Else, use `next()` instead of `nextUntil()` as the `tr` you want to hide is the closest sibling of the `tr` that has the button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
    
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr.test').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GridGlyphs';
  src: url('../MvcGrid/Fonts/GridGlyphs.woff') format('woff');
}

.mvc-grid {
  line-height: 1.25em;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.mvc-grid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mvc-grid th {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  position: relative;
}

.mvc-grid th,
.mvc-grid td {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  padding: 0.75em;
}

.mvc-grid .filterable {
  padding-right: 3.5em;
}

.mvc-grid .sortable,
.mvc-grid .mvc-grid-filter {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mvc-grid .asc::after {
  padding-left: 3px;
  content: '\2193';
}

.mvc-grid .desc::after {
  padding-left: 3px;
  content: '\2191';
}

.mvc-grid-hidden,
.mvc-grid-options {
  display: none;
}

.mvc-grid-filter {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  font-family: 'GridGlyphs';
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 2.75em;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-filter:focus,
.mvc-grid-filter:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  color: inherit;
}

.mvc-grid-filter::before {
  content: '\0041';
}

.mvc-grid-filter.applied::before {
  content: '\0042';
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .filterable {
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters th div {
  display: flex;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value {
  border: 0.5px solid #aaaaaa;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 0.2em;
  flex: 1;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters input.mvc-grid-value {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value.invalid {
  outline-color: #dc3545;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value::placeholder {
  color: #bbbbbb;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #bbbbbb;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-filter {
  border: 0.5px solid #aaaaaa;
  flex: 0 0 2.125em;
  position: static;
  height: 2.125em;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters [readonly] {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters.mvc-grid-headers .filterable {
  padding: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters.mvc-grid-headers .mvc-grid-value {
  padding: 0.625em 3.5em 0.625em 0.75em;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters.mvc-grid-headers .mvc-grid-filter {
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
}

.mvc-grid-popup {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 12em;
  font-size: 1rem;
  z-index: 1100;
}

.mvc-grid-popup.mvc-grid-guid-filter {
  min-width: 20em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-arrow {
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  top: -8px;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-arrow::after {
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 9px solid #cccccc;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  z-index: -1;
  left: -8px;
  top: -1px;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-content {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-group {
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-operator {
  text-align: center;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-actions {
  padding: 0.4em 0 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-value,
.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-method,
.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-operator {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0 0.2em;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 100%;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-operator {
  width: auto;
}

.mvc-grid-popup input.mvc-grid-value {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-value.invalid {
  outline-color: #dc3545;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-apply,
.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-cancel {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 4em;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-apply {
  background-color: #28a745;
  border-color: #28a745;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-apply:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2em rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.5);
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-cancel {
  background-color: #dc3545;
  border-color: #dc3545;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-cancel:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2em rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.5);
}

.mvc-grid-pager,
.mvc-grid-empty-row {
  text-align: center;
}

.mvc-grid-pager button {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  min-width: 2em;
  color: #337ab7;
}

.mvc-grid-pager button:focus,
.mvc-grid-pager button:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: #014c8c;
}

.mvc-grid-pager .active,
.mvc-grid-pager .active:focus,
.mvc-grid-pager .active:hover {
  background-color: #0275d8;
  border-color: #0275d8;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.mvc-grid-pager .disabled,
.mvc-grid-pager .disabled:focus,
.mvc-grid-pager .disabled:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: #777777;
  outline: none;
}

.mvc-grid-page-sizes {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-page-sizes select {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  font: inherit;
}

.mvc-grid-page-sizes input {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 2.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-loader {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  justify-content: center;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: wait;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-loading {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mvc-grid-loading>div>div {
  animation: loader-points 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 0.75em;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-loading>div>div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.mvc-grid-loading>div>div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

@keyframes loader-points {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="test">
      <td><button class="clickme">collapse</button></td>
      <td>name1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8" class="parent">
        <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="" data-filter-mode="ExcelRow" data-source-url="">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr class="mvc-grid-headers ">
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
      <td><button class="clickme">collapse</button></td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8" class="parent">

        <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="" data-filter-mode="ExcelRow" data-source-url="">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr class="mvc-grid-headers ">
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
      <td><button class="clickme">collapse</button></td>
      <td>name3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8" class="parent">

        <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="" data-filter-mode="ExcelRow" data-source-url="">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr class="mvc-grid-headers ">
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go up to the parent `tr` using `.closest('tr')` then select the next one using `.next('tr')`:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').slideToggle('slow');
```

**NOTE:** Make sure there's no duplicate id `test`, and use common classes instead.

**NOTE 2:** The `nextUntil()` you were using will work too, but it will search through the successors when there's no need for this, the `next()` method is faster since it will target the next element directly.

**Working snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'GridGlyphs';
  src: url('../MvcGrid/Fonts/GridGlyphs.woff') format('woff');
}

.mvc-grid {
  line-height: 1.25em;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.mvc-grid table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.mvc-grid th {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  position: relative;
}

.mvc-grid th,
.mvc-grid td {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  padding: 0.75em;
}

.mvc-grid .filterable {
  padding-right: 3.5em;
}

.mvc-grid .sortable,
.mvc-grid .mvc-grid-filter {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mvc-grid .asc::after {
  padding-left: 3px;
  content: '\2193';
}

.mvc-grid .desc::after {
  padding-left: 3px;
  content: '\2191';
}

.mvc-grid-hidden,
.mvc-grid-options {
  display: none;
}

.mvc-grid-filter {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
  font-family: 'GridGlyphs';
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 2.75em;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-filter:focus,
.mvc-grid-filter:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  color: inherit;
}

.mvc-grid-filter::before {
  content: '\0041';
}

.mvc-grid-filter.applied::before {
  content: '\0042';
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .filterable {
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters th div {
  display: flex;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value {
  border: 0.5px solid #aaaaaa;
  margin-right: 0.25em;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 0.2em;
  flex: 1;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters input.mvc-grid-value {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value.invalid {
  outline-color: #dc3545;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value::placeholder {
  color: #bbbbbb;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-value:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #bbbbbb;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters .mvc-grid-filter {
  border: 0.5px solid #aaaaaa;
  flex: 0 0 2.125em;
  position: static;
  height: 2.125em;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters [readonly] {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters.mvc-grid-headers .filterable {
  padding: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters.mvc-grid-headers .mvc-grid-value {
  padding: 0.625em 3.5em 0.625em 0.75em;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-row-filters.mvc-grid-headers .mvc-grid-filter {
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
}

.mvc-grid-popup {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 12em;
  font-size: 1rem;
  z-index: 1100;
}

.mvc-grid-popup.mvc-grid-guid-filter {
  min-width: 20em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-arrow {
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  top: -8px;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-arrow::after {
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 9px solid #cccccc;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  z-index: -1;
  left: -8px;
  top: -1px;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-content {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-group {
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-operator {
  text-align: center;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .popup-actions {
  padding: 0.4em 0 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-value,
.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-method,
.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-operator {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0 0.2em;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 100%;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-operator {
  width: auto;
}

.mvc-grid-popup input.mvc-grid-value {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-value.invalid {
  outline-color: #dc3545;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-apply,
.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-cancel {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 0.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 4em;
  color: #ffffff;
  outline: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-apply {
  background-color: #28a745;
  border-color: #28a745;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-apply:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2em rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.5);
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-cancel {
  background-color: #dc3545;
  border-color: #dc3545;
  margin-left: 0.3em;
}

.mvc-grid-popup .mvc-grid-cancel:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2em rgba(220, 53, 69, 0.5);
}

.mvc-grid-pager,
.mvc-grid-empty-row {
  text-align: center;
}

.mvc-grid-pager button {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  min-width: 2em;
  color: #337ab7;
}

.mvc-grid-pager button:focus,
.mvc-grid-pager button:hover {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: #014c8c;
}

.mvc-grid-pager .active,
.mvc-grid-pager .active:focus,
.mvc-grid-pager .active:hover {
  background-color: #0275d8;
  border-color: #0275d8;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.mvc-grid-pager .disabled,
.mvc-grid-pager .disabled:focus,
.mvc-grid-pager .disabled:hover {
  background-color: #efefef;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: #777777;
  outline: none;
}

.mvc-grid-page-sizes {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-page-sizes select {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  font: inherit;
}

.mvc-grid-page-sizes input {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0.25em;
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 2.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-loader {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  justify-content: center;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: wait;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.mvc-grid-loading {
  opacity: 1;
}

.mvc-grid-loading>div>div {
  animation: loader-points 1.4s infinite ease-in-out both;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 0 0.75em;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
}

.mvc-grid-loading>div>div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}

.mvc-grid-loading>div>div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}

@keyframes loader-points {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="test">
      <td><button class="clickme">collapse</button></td>
      <td>name1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8" class="parent">
        <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="" data-filter-mode="ExcelRow" data-source-url="">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr class="mvc-grid-headers ">
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
      <td><button class="clickme">collapse</button></td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8" class="parent">

        <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="" data-filter-mode="ExcelRow" data-source-url="">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr class="mvc-grid-headers ">
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
      <td><button class="clickme">collapse</button></td>
      <td>name3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="8" class="parent">

        <div class="mvc-grid" data-name="" data-filter-mode="ExcelRow" data-source-url="">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr class="mvc-grid-headers ">
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span class="mvc-grid-header-title ">Test1</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```